# Input string is not in a correct format error

Tags: c#, string, csv, typeerror, unhandled-exception

C#

```cs
public static int getAge(int yearOfBirth) 
{
    int CurrentYear = DateTime.Now.Year;
    int age = CurrentYear - yearOfBirth;
    return age;
}
```

In this function, I calculate age according to the birth year as an integer.

```cs
public static void distributionByAge()
{
    int child = 0; //between 0-16
    int youngAdults = 0; //between 17-30
    int middleAged = 0; //between 30-55
    int oldAged = 0; //above 55

    var lines = File.ReadAllLines(@"data.csv"); // read file

    foreach (var line in lines) // Reads file line by line
    {
        string[] values = line.Split(","); // Split each value
        string birthYear = values[2]; // Birth year is value number 2 of each string/line

        int age = getAge(Int32.Parse(birthYear));

        // Check the age range
        if (age>=0 || age<=16)
        {
            // If the age is between 0 and 16 increment count
            child++;
        }
        else if (age>=17 || age<=30)
        {
            // If the age is between 17 and 30 increment count
            youngAdults++;
        }
        else if (age>=31 || age<=55)
        {
            // If the age is between 31 and 55, increment count
            middleAged++;
        }
        else
        {
            // If tge afe is above 55, increment count
            oldAged++;
        }
    }

    // Print results in percentages

    int total = child + youngAdults + middleAged + oldAged;

    Console.WriteLine("-------------------------------------------------------------------");

    Console.WriteLine("Child: ");
    Console.WriteLine(getPercentage(total, child) + "%");

    Console.WriteLine("-------------------------------------------------------------------");

    Console.WriteLine("Young Adults: ");
    Console.WriteLine(getPercentage(total, youngAdults) + "%");

    Console.WriteLine("-------------------------------------------------------------------");

    Console.WriteLine("Middle-Aged Adults: ");
    Console.WriteLine(getPercentage(total, middleAged) + "%");
    Console.WriteLine("-------------------------------------------------------------------");

    Console.WriteLine("Old-Aged Adults: ");
    Console.WriteLine(getPercentage(total, oldAged) + "%");
}
```

These are my functions and I am trying to read the CSV file, take the year of birth information and calculate the ages according to it. I had to convert string type to int but I get unhandled exception and wrong type errors.

Comment: [Debug your code!](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/get-started/csharp/tutorial-debugger?view=vs-2022). `if (age>=0 || age<=16)` will always match. Use `if (age>=0 && age<=16)` instead.

Comment: Could you please show exceptions and errors? Could you add an extract (two or three lines) of data.csv? Anyway... if "Birth year is value number 2" then it should be `string birthYear = values[1];`

Comment: I suspect there's a non-integer value somewhere in `birthYear`. I would recommend first checking the input file for any errors, for example using CSV Lint plug-in for Notepad++ to technically validate the data https://github.com/BdR76/CSVLint and then either fix the data file, or send it back to whoever provided the data and ask them to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty clear from the error message that somewhere in your data.csv there's a row where the second value is either missing or can't be parsed as an int.

It might be something like `22a` or `2.0` or even `banana`.
The way to correctly handle such things are to use `TryParse` instead of `Parse`, and when `TryParse` return false, you should decide what you want to do with the data in that row. Personally, I would probably just write it to console and ignore it later on in the program.

something like this:

```cs
// instead of int age = getAge(Int32.Parse(birthYear));
if(!int.TryParse(birthYear, out var year))
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0} is not a valid birth year", birthYear);
    continue;
}
var age = getAge(year);
// rest of your foreach loop here
```

Comment: I would throw an exception and just let the code crash, but do make sure to output the line number of the datafile in the exception message. Then I would just return the data file to whoever compiled it, and ask them to fix the birthyear column. I think in the long run, that's a better approach than trying to fix bad data in code and then let it continue with probably incorrect data.

Comment: @BdR Where did I suggest to try and fix the bad data? 
As a rule of thumb, when working with data you can't control there's always a chance that the data will be corrupt. Your code should anticipate things like that and crushing the entire program over one line of ill formatted data seems like a bad choice to me. IMO, Exceptions should be thrown under exceptional circumstances, and corrupt data is anything but exceptional.